# Button Link Formatting - Center and Match Width

Tags: html, css

I've created a couple of simple buttons using a link and some CSS to give it a background and I'm trying to center it on my page. However, because the text in one of the buttons is longer than the other, the buttons are of different sizes and for consistency, I'd like them to be the same width.

How can I keep these buttons the same size? Trying to float them and use percentage widths results in them not being centered. The relevant markup is below.

```
<section class="buttonsSection">
    <a class="button" href="#">Very Long Sentence</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Short Phrase</a>
</section>


.button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    color: white;
}

.buttonsSection{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.buttonsSection a {
    margin: 3px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/eTvCp/11/

**Answer**
While both of the answer below are valid, I'm updating my answer to using Flexbox. [Most modern browsers have excellent support for it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), including IE11 which will be released in the very near future. Flexbox appears to provide a much better solution to doing complex layouts which requires less effort than it's alternatives, such as floating items.

Comment: Looks centered to me, where are you having problems?

Comment: The button widths don't match. I can get the width to match by floating them, but then they aren't centered. I want them to be both centered and the same width.

Comment: Added an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done with **[flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**:

```
.button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 150px; /* Fixed width links */
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    color: white;
    margin: 3px;
}

.callToAction {
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: flex; /* Magic! */
    justify-content: center; /* Centering magic! */
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eTvCp/9/)**

Answer (score 2):

use a fixed width with `inline-block` on the buttons.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eTvCp/6/)

```
.button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%; /*or any other width that suites you best*/
}

.callToAction {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

using `inline-block` provides a little-bit of margin between the elements (caused by a white-space in the HTML) so I removed the marin from the CSS, but you can put it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button 
 {
     width: 150px; /* Your custome size */
     background-color:deepskyblue;
     color: white;
     margin: 3px;
     padding: 10px 15px;
 }

Section a
 {
    width: 150px; /* for your all buttons */
 }
```