# Flexbox - Vertically Center and Match Size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two buttons next to each other using flex and I have their contents vertically centered, which work great so far. However, when my site is viewed on mobile pages (using responsive design to scale the page), the second button, which has less text in it becomes a different size than it's companion.

So, the goal is to vertically align the text on my buttons as well as to have the two buttons always match each others size.

```
<section class="buttonsSection">
    <a class="button" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Short Phrase</a>
</section>

.button {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    color: white;  
    margin: 3px;
   text-align: center;
}

.buttonsSection {
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

body
{
    width: 20%; /*Simulate page being reduced in size (i.e. on mobile)*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/WmZPg/
If the problem isn't obvious right away, try reducing the width of the Result window.

Comment: use the solution I gave you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071114/button-link-formatting-center-and-match-width/19071182#19071182) it will work with all resolutions.

Comment: @acvrahamcool The solution you posted on the other question appears to have the same problem. Try reducing the Result windows of your solution. You will notice that the button on the left is larger in height than the button on the right. Your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eTvCp/6/).

Comment: with my solution its just a matter of creating `equal height column` which is pretty easy. but I found a solution to your CSS.

Comment: Exact duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063770/how-to-vertically-align-and-stretch-content-using-css-flexbox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063770/how-to-vertically-align-and-stretch-content-using-css-flexbox), was to set the buttonsSection to flex and center, and setting the button to flex, column and center.

See Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/Nbknc/

```
.button {
    ...

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttonsSection {
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice one.. +1

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, and the answer is found in the question it is a duplicate of, the question should be closed rather than copying the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @cimmanon: The solution to this question wasn't copied from the duplicate, but rather inferred from it.

Comment: This works great! =) I would just invert the order that .button and .buttonsSection is presented. I would put the container on top and the .button on bottom to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `align-items: stretch;` to `.buttonsSection`

see that <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/WmZPg/1/)</kbd>

```
.buttonsSection {
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

also: when using `flex` you'll have to pay attention to the vendors specific prefix's.
read more about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

### Update:

If you're using my original proposal, you can also control the vertical-alignment.

check out this <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WmZPg/2/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (same)
    
        Very Long Word
        Short Phrase

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    width: 20%; /*Simulate page being reduced in size (i.e. on mobile)*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.buttonsSection
{
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 3px 0;
}


.button
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px; /*Or any other width you want*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does fix the height, but now the text in the second button isn't vertically centered.

Comment: Your update does fix the vertical alignment, but now the buttons are not the same width.

Comment: so instead of max-width, use width. see that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmZPg/3/)

Comment: Using `align-items: stretch` overwrites `align-items: center`, which is being used for vertical centering purposes.